# Splitting a list without creating an empty list in Prolog

Tags: list, split, prolog, append

```
split(L,X,Y):-append(X,Y,L).
```

creates 4 splits as follows:

```
X = [],
Y = [1, 2, 3] ;

X = [1],
Y = [2, 3] ;

X = [1, 2],
Y = [3] ;

X = [1, 2, 3],
Y = [] ;
```

I want to eliminate the empty list  created during split and keep only combinations which do not have empty list that is

```
X = [1],
Y = [2, 3] ;

X = [1, 2],
Y = [3] ;
```

Comment: What have you tried? Include, as conditions in your `split` predicate, that you want `X` and `Y` to have at least one element with head and tail. If you aren't sure how to do that, do a lookup on Prolog list notation.

Comment: Please can you specify how to include the condition in split predicate.

Comment: You could just write: `split(L, [X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :- append([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], L).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first specify the pattern for `X` and `Y`, by unifying these with a "cons":

```
split(L, X, Y) :-
    X = [_|_],
    Y = [_|_],
    append(X, Y, L).
```

The advantage of using this approach, is that you will probably safe some cycles, since `append/3` will not propose certain solutions that are empty lists, that then have to be filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve your problem, as said in the comments, you have to add a condition that checks if `X` or `Y` are empty, in this way:

```
split(L,X,Y):- 
    append(X,Y,L),
    x\=[], 
    Y\=[].
```

Why the check is done after `append/3`? `X = []` is true because `X` can be unified with `[]` when it is still uninstantiated. When you call `split/3`, initially `X` and `Y` are uninstantiated (if you use the tracer you can see something like `_4604\=[]`): `X = []` succeds and so the negation fails and the program returns `false` if you put `X\=[]` and `Y\=[]` before `append/3`.

To better understand, i suggest you to read [this](http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node75.html) article.